# jQuery: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression?

Tags: jquery, syntax-error, expression

I am trying to port some simple piece of code to a newer jquery version (1.10).

I run into a problem that puzzles me. For some reason this expression:

```
toolbar.find('th#title').find('div input.shorty-filter:[value!=""]').length
```

gives me an unexpected error:

*Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div input.shorty-filter:[value!='']*

This worked fine for ages and I don't see any issue with this expression. What do I miss?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Argh! How obvious! Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3550xz6r/

```
toolbar.find('th#title').find('div input[value!=""].shorty-filter').length;
```

Comment: Yes, his answer was correct, but generally for readability, I would attach the [value] selector to the input declaration. Remove the : and then add the class selector on the end.

Comment: I'd say the readability part depends on the situation. In this case the class is the more important filtering aspect. Therefore it should preceed further filters... But thanks!